# HTML href path weird behavior

Tags: html, url, href

I observed a weird behavior in this website: http://www.tribunalconstitucional.pt/tc/acordaos/

There is a button to print the page with the following `href`:

```html
<a href="/tc/acordaos/?impressao=1"> ... </a>
```

Wasn't it supposed to build the link like this, repeating the `/tc/acordaos/` part?

```
http://www.tribunalconstitucional.pt/tc/acordaos/tc/acordaos/?impressao=1
```

Why browsers build the link "correctly" as follows? Am I missing something in here?

```
http://www.tribunalconstitucional.pt/tc/acordaos/?impressao=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefixed `/` in the `href` means the root (the hostname).

So something like this for `example.com/doo`:

`href="/foo/bar"` would go to `example.com/foo/bar`.

If the prefixed `/` wasn't added, it would go to `example.com/doo/foo/bar`

Comment: Wow. Of course. Thanks! Now I feel really stupid for having asked that.